# Unable to create DynamoDB table with LSI using dynamodb-data-mapper-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to setup a DynamoDB database in Node.js using the official AWS library [dynamodb-data-mapper-js](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js) to create persistent model objects and data mappers. However it looks like the don't mention anything about creating tables with Local Sencondary Indexes or either GSI.

I found [an issue in Github](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/issues/93) with a reference on how to create a table with LSI, the provided example explains the difference between referencing a `rangeKey` and declaring a LSI:

```js
@table('items')
class Item {
  @hashKey({ // <-- this is your normal hash key (shared by table and of LSI)
    indexKeyConfigurations:{
      ItemIdIndex: 'HASH' // The key (ItemIdIndex) is the name of the index; the value is the key type ('HASH' or 'RANGE')
    }
  })
  itemId: string;

  @rangeKey() // <-- this is your normal range key (not part of LSI)
  displayName: string;

  @attribute({
    // And this other attribute acts as the LSI's RangeKey
    indexKeyConfigurations: {
      ItemIdIndex: 'RANGE'
    }
  })
  foo: string;

  @attribute()
  bar: string;
}
```

However, I created a table with exactly the same table model and I get the following error:

```sh
Error: No options provided for ItemIdIndex index at indexDefinitions
```

I couldn't get any more information, the documentation doesn't say anything about LSI or GSI even they say they support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the problem was that you need to specify some options about the type of index when you are creating the table. For example you need to at least specify if it's a LSI or GSI and which keys must the index include.

```
mapper.createTable(Item, {
    readCapacityUnits: 5,
    writeCapacityUnits: 5,
    indexOptions: {
        LocalIndexExample: {
            type: 'local',
            projection: 'all',
        },
        GlobalIndexExample: {
            type: 'global',
            projection: ['createdBy', 'createdAt'],
            readCapacityUnits: 2,
            writeCapacityUnits: 3,
        },
    },
})
```